# loading data in bulk into a postgreSQL table that has a ForeignKey using SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in PostgreSQL/SQLAlchemy.

```
def load_books():
with open('C:\\Users\\books_raw.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        record = line.split('$') # split at delimiter

        book_isbn = record[0].strip('"')
        book_title = record[1]
        book_authors = record[2]
        book_avg_rating = record[2]
        book_format = record[4]
        book_img_url = record[5]
        book_num_pages = record[6]
        book_pub_date = record[7]
        book_publisher = record[8].strip()  # ESTABLISH RELATIONSHIP

        book = Books(title=book_title, isbn=book_isbn, authors=book_authors, avg_rating=book_avg_rating, format=book_format,
                     img_url=book_img_url, num_pages=book_num_pages, pub_date=book_pub_date, publisher=Publication(name=book_publisher))
        session.add(book)

session.commit()
count = session.query(Books).count()
print(count, ' books added to the database')
```

My problem was with the relationship. If you see this part of the code:

```
publisher=Publication(name=book_publisher))
```

here i don't want the record to be inserted into the table, but just establish a relation with an existing record in the main table. Any ideas how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In for loop check if `publisher` in db or not if not in db then can create new one and save book with this publisher:

```
for line in file.readlines(): 
    ...
    publisher=Publication.query.filter(name=book_publisher).first()
    if not publisher:
        publisher=Publication(name=book_publisher)
    book = Books(..., publisher=publisher)
```

Comment: thank you. i got the answer. queried row from the main table via an instance variable and then accessed the primary_key (id) from the instance. used that as relationship

Answer (score 0):

```
r = session.query(Publication).filter(Publication.name == book_publisher).first()

        book = Books(title=book_title, isbn=book_isbn, authors=book_authors, avg_rating=book_avg_rating, format=book_format,
                     img_url=book_img_url, num_pages=book_num_pages, pub_date=book_pub_date, pub_id=r.id)
        session.add(book)
```